# ajax response cause an issue with html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i am working on a form and i am sending ajax call on dropdown onchange every thing is fine, but the only thing I cannot understand is when I display that html(response) in the response div all the tr and td disappears I firebug it and try to find out the reason but all is in vain.

The div with id txtHint is a response div and I want to replace the `<tr>....</tr>` with `<tr>....</tr>` ajax response return me

```
 <div id='txtHint'>
    <?php while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($select_recrds)){?>            
         <tr>
            <td field="itemid" width="80" sortable="true"><a href=""><?php  echo $rows['ee'];?></a></td>
            <td field="productid" width="100" sortable="true"><?php  echo $rows['ss'];?></td>
            <td field="listprice" width="80" align="right" sortable="true"><?php  echo $rows['cc'];?></td>
            <td field="unitcost" width="80" align="right" sortable="true"><?php  echo $rows['bb'];?></td>
            <td field="status" width="160" align="center"><?php  echo $rows['xx'];?></td>
        </tr>        
   <?php }?>
 </div>
```

Here is the ajax response

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

       echo  '<tr>';
           echo       '<td field="itemid" width="80" sortable="true"><a href="">'.$row["ee"].'</a></td>';
           echo       '<td field="productid" width="100" sortable="true">'.$row["ss"].'</td>';
           echo       '<td field="listprice" width="80" align="right" sortable="true">'.$row["cc"].'</td>';
           echo       '<td field="unitcost" width="80" align="right" sortable="true">'.$row["bb"].'</td>';
           echo       '<td field="status" width="160" align="center">'.$row["xx"].'</td>';
           echo       '</tr>';
 }
```

both seem the same but only difference is the record it contains so don't worry about it.

When I alert the response html its fine, like in image below:

[image]

but what i recieve response div is

```
  <div id="txtHint"><a href="">12</a>Bolt-Ons2013-09-25 14:28:520000-00-00 00:00:00in progress<a href="">4</a>Bolt-Ons2013-09-25 14:28:470000-00-00 00:00:00in progress</div>
```

Why do the tr and tds disappear and how do I solve this issue?

Below is my ajax call

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
    if (str=="")
    {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","filter_data.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your AJAX call?

Comment: You can't have `tr` elements directly inside a `div`, they need to be in a `table`.

Comment: then how to replace the tr with my ajax response tr

Comment: because my tr is inside while loop and i want to repeat the tr not the table

Answer (score 0):

For help you to debug, Try to put your result in a variable like :

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

 $var.='<tr>';
 $var.='<td field="itemid" width="80" sortable="true"><a href="">'.$row["order_id"].'</a></td>';
 $var.='<td field="productid" width="100" sortable="true">'.$row["order_type"].'</td>';
 $var.='<td field="listprice" width="80" align="right" sortable="true">'.$row["order_created"].'</td>';
 $var.='<td field="unitcost" width="80" align="right" sortable="true">'.$row["order_updated"].'</td>';
 $var.='<td field="status" width="160" align="center">'.$row["status"].'</td>';
 $var.='</tr>';
 }
```

And after, make

```
mail('yourmail@mail.com', 'test', $var);
```

And see in your mail the result.

In your Html code, do this :

```
<table>
    <tbody id='txtHint'>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i did as you mentioned but its giving me whole table now